# Getting Started with Repository Pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

I'm trying to get started with the repository pattern and ASP.NET MVC, and I can't help but believe I'm missing something.  Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but it seems to me like an implementation violates DRY exponentially.  For example, in my (admittedly novice) understanding in order to implement this, I would have to:

1. Create my database model (Currently using Linq to Sql)
2. Create a IRepository for each concept (table or group of related tables)
3. Create an implementation for each IRepository
4. Do we return L2S objects or some sort of DTO?
5. Create viewmodels which either are containers or copies of the data
6. Use some method of DI (Windsor or Unity?) on the controllers

While I realize scalability and portability come at an expense, it just feels like I'm missing something?

Comment: You can create a generic repository, and simply implement the spcific you need...

Comment: You might want to check out the Ninject website source (at Nate Kohari's Github) for MVC or BlogEngine.NET which implements Repository pattern in ASP.NET WebForms (actually Mads implements it as a class library so it is easier to understand when you don't have all the MVC stuff like controllers&views around).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to implement the Repository Pattern in LINQ 2 SQL and it doesn't work very well, mainly because L2S doesn't use POCOs and you have to map to DTOs all the time as you mention. Although you could use something like AutoMapper, L2S just isn't a very good fit for the Repository Pattern.

If you're going to use the Repository Pattern (and I would recommend it), try a different data access technology such as NHibernate or Entity Framework 4.0's POCO support.

Also you wouldn't create a Repository for each and every table, you create a Repository per **Domain Aggregate**, and use the Repository to access the Aggregate's **Root** entity only. For instance, if you have an e-commerce app, with `Order` and `OrderItem` entities, an Order has one-or-many OrderItems. These 2 entities are part of a single Aggregate, and the `Order` entity is the **Aggregate Root**. You'd only create an OrderRepository in this case, NOT an OrderItemRepository as well. If you want to add new OrderItems you'd do so by getting a reference to the Order entity, then adding the new OrderItem to the Order's Items collection, then saving the Order using your OrderRepository. This technique is called [Domain](http://thinkddd.com/) [Driven](http://domaindrivendesign.org/) [Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design), and it's a very powerful paradigm to use if you have a complex Domain Model and business rules in your application. But it can be over kill in simple applications, so you have to ask yourself does the complexity of your Domain Model warrant using this approach.

In terms is adhering to DRY, normally I create a base Repository class that has common methods for Save, Delete, FetchById, that sort of thing. As long as my Repository classes implement this base class (OrderRepository, ProductRepository etc.) then they get these methods for free and the code is DRY. This was easy to do in NHibernate because of POCO support, but impossible to do in Linq 2 SQL.

Don't worry too much about sending your Domain Models directly to the view, most dedicated ViewModels look almost identical to the Domain Model anyway, so what's the point. Although I tend to avoid using the DM for posting data back to the server because of under/overposting security concerns.

If you follow this POCO approach (and ditch LINQ 2 SQL, honestly!!), you end up with only one class (your POCO entity) instead of 3 (L2S class, DTO and ViewModel).

It is possible to implement the Repository Pattern badly, so tread carefully, read a few tutorials, blog posts books etc. (I recommend [Steven Sanderson's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228865), especially look at the Pre-Requisites chapter) But once mastered, it becomes a very powerful way to organise the complexity of hydrating Model objects to and from a data-store. And if you use Repository interfaces (IOrderRepository etc.) and have them injected via an IOC Container, you also gain the benefits of maintainability and unit testability.

Comment: I used to use my Domain Model classes in Views and it was working and all but I was constantly running into issues when I had to make custom binders, special extensions, etc. etc. problems with persistance to XML/SQL DB so I decided to create another set of ViewModel classes, which yes, do look almost the same but not entirely the same. You can tweak ViewModel classes easier and make them more applicable to what the View needs. Then I use ValueInjector (new great tool, better than Automapper) to sync ViewModel and Model instances.

Comment: I think you'll find that LINQ2SQL does have POCO support in so much that it only requires you to add attributes to a POCO class for mapping. EF4 doesn't support this unless you get the CTP, and then it only supports POCOs to the same degree as L2S. Part of Steve's reasoning for staying with L2S for his book was because of the POCO support. If you want to separate POCOs to be agnostic of data implementation you can make the properties virtual and override them in a derived class that is dependant on your data implementation. Even NHibernate requires you to make properties virtual (lazy loading)

Answer (score 3):

Do you understand why your doing these things or are you just following along with a blog article or other source?

Don't implement the Repository pattern because its the new hotness.  Implement it because you understand how these separation of concerns helps your project and overall quality of your code.

From your ?'s in your question it sounds like you need to do some more reading before you implement.  Your probably missing a meaningful understanding of the overall architecture approach.  Please don't take this the wrong way and I'm not trying to be negative.

Side Rant:

Obviously something is missing from the newest repository hotness picture because the confusion about implementation details like single Repository vs. Many/Grouped "DTO or not to DTO" are just so ambiguous and subjective.  This is a "nickle question" that pops up again and again.

Comment: Generally speaking, my reasoning is because I don't want to have LINQ Code dominating my controllers.  It will turn the project into an unmaintainable mess.  Also, it seems that all the articles point to repository "hotness" as a panacea for layered design, testing, abstraction, and world hunger.  No offense was taken by your post, as I am trying to gather "a meaningful understanding" of the system.

Comment: LINQ code should not normally be present in your controller. Your controller should depend on an abstraction of a repository (interface) in order to call methods to get data. The implementation of the repository should handle the data access.

Comment: @Matt Murrell Have you ever used LINQ in your controllers before?

Comment: @Matt. You'll often see posts with that type of structure in the same way that you'd see it in a code-behind page in WebForms. ***It isn't good design*** but convenient for showing off functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This has been brought up before, at first glance certain aspects of properly separating concerns does seem to violate DRY.

As you've mentioned MVC have you read Steve Sanderson's Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework book? It spends a great deal of time explaining why using the repository pattern is a good idea.

You might find that, for the projects you're working on, it isn't appropriatte, that's okay. Don't use it and see if you come across problems that this could have addressed. You don't need to be a developer for long to realise how crucial it is to keep different parts of your application as loosely coupled as possible.

Comment: + 1 to Steven Sanderson's book, easily the best book on ASP.NET MVC IMHO, and it explains Repository + DDD really well.